# Codeigniter Project on Github File Upload Problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, github, heroku

I have Codeigniter Project on Github and deployed with Heroku. I upload thousand times on other websites but when we are talking about Github and Heroku I saw a problem. This problem is when I upload my file from website no error messages given and I cannot see my file. By the way the path I gave is true I am sure.

Can anyone have a project like that?

Comment: Permissions, most likely

Comment: What is the error message about, authentication!

Comment: dear @PedroSerpa . We are talking about local files' permissions or not? I checked permissions and they all have 7's.